# Remove outliers in many variables of a dataset

Tags: r, outliers

In the dataset I am working on, there are 24 variables and all of them have the outliers of 99. So I need to remove 99 from all these variables. Is there a quick way I can do this? I can do this one by one by using:

```
education <- subset(ex1, ex1$education<99)
```

`ex1` is my dataset, can I think I need to use `data.frame` to do this?

Comment: So what language is this...?

Comment: it is R? Actually, I am trying this one but it is not working: 

rm.outlier(ex1, fill = FALSE, median = FALSE, opposite = FALSE)
R said it didnt recognize rm.outlier

Comment: If it is R then tag it as R. Or at the very least specify it is the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really talking about outlier's or about a flag value of 99 that you want to remove? The latter would simply be:

```
ex1[ex1 == 99] <- NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Definitely suggest using a `data.frame` and if you want to remove all rows with `99` then you can do:

```
ex1 <- data.frame(
  a = sample(90:99,100, replace=TRUE),
  b = sample(90:99,100, replace=TRUE),
  c = sample(90:99,100, replace=TRUE),
  d = sample(90:99,100, replace=TRUE),
  e = sample(90:99,100, replace=TRUE),
  f = sample(90:99,100, replace=TRUE)
)

print(nrow(ex1))

ex1 <- ex1[complete.cases(sapply(ex1, function(val) ifelse(val == 99, NA, val))),]

print(nrow(ex1))
```

(The `print()`'s are just to show that there are a different # of rows)

otherwise, you should use [@infominer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2747709/infominer)'s suggestion (which was literally just edited to do a simpler/alternate version of the remove).

Comment: you finished my thought, by using complete cases!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#assuming ex1 is a data.frame
#if you want to remove the 99s completely
ex.wo.outliers <-sapply(ex1, function(x) subset(x, x!=99))
#if you want to keep the 99s as NAs
ex.withsub <-sapply(ex1, function(x) ifelse(x == 99,NA,x)
```

the first will remove all rows with 99s in any of your variables
the second  will take care of all your variables and make them NA

I recommend the second, as this will preserve the dimensions of your data.frame.
The second will result in different lengths for each variable, in case you have a row with some 99s and some valid values.